# wordpress pagination get current page number from url

Tags: wordpress

I need to extract the value of "page" i.e 5 from this url - http://snypher.local/photos/page/5
What should I do to extract it in Wordpress? I am not able to get it from the $_GET super global.

Answer (score 17):

use `get_query_var` example `$page = get_query_var('paged');` in your case it's `5`

Answer (score 10):

its work fine i've tested on my current WP (version 3.5.1)

```
$current_page = max( 1, get_query_var('paged') );
$total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
echo 'Page '.$current_page.' of '.$total_pages;
```

Result = Page 3 of 51

Answer (score 7):

```
function get_url_var($name)
{
    $strURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $arrVals = explode("/",$strURL);
    $found = 0;
    foreach ($arrVals as $index => $value) 
    {
        if($value == $name) $found = $index;
    }
    $place = $found + 1;
    return $arrVals[$place];
}

$page = get_url_var('page');
```

I have used this function to get the value of the variable page from the url.

Comment: Nice start, but it doesn't work if 'page' is not present in the URL. Consider replacing `return $arrVals[$place];` with this: `return ($found == 0) ? 1 : $arrVals[$place];` - such that if the 'page' is not in URI we automatically assume that user is on the first page.

Answer (score 2):

Found a nice solution and I'd like to share it here for I was looking for exactly the same thing!

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-current-page-number-for-paginated-posts

So it's like:

```
<?php echo '(Page '.$page.' of '.$numpages.')'; ?>
```