# How to get page number in this custom wordpress link?

Tags: php, wordpress, numbers

I am trying to get the page number from the URL "http://www.someurl.com/?alpha=A/page/2", but it keeps printing out "0", not "2". Please help.

```
$current_page = get_query_var('paged');
echo "current page is $current_page";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you question, you want to get number 2 from `http://www.someurl.com/?alpha=A/page/2` string.

You could use some `php` string manipulation functions:

```
$curr_link = "http://www.someurl.com/?alpha=A/page/2";
$page_num  = substr($curr_link, -1, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I have to use this to get the page number.

Answer (score 1):

This should echo "Page 2 of 2" See: [wordpress pagination get current page number from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281395/wordpress-pagination-get-current-page-number-from-url)

`<?php echo '(Page '.$page.' of '.$numpages.')'; ?>`

Comment: The $page variable doesn't work in this particular URL structure due to the custom parameter "alpha" that I created.

Comment: Ah caught that after A.S. Roma's response. Just gave him an upvote.