# Get page parameter from woocommerce product url

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have woocommerce set up in a site and it has an ajax switch. With this the view of products changes from list to grid and vice versa. In the ajax call, I have queried the products again through a custom query using this code

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;    
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'product_cat' => $_GET['category'],
    'paged' => $paged
);
$count = 0;
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But I dont get the required output from get_query_var(10). The url of the product page is as follows.

> https:example.com/product-category/producers/arturo/page/2/?view=grid

Through this url all I need is the page parameter with value 2. How can I fetch it in the ajax call.

Comment: So you basically just need what page you're on? I.e. 2 in this case. You could just get the entire page url and make a regex to match the number after *page/*.

Comment: @Martin Yeah I thought of that but it seems kind of bad and not efficient. I wanted a way through wordpress if possible

Comment: Another way if possible would be if you could convert the page count to be a `GET` variable like the view is.

Comment: Woocommerce does the functionality of adding it like that. I cannot change the plugin code

Comment: The `$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;` seems to be the correct way for fetching the page number.  If you echo it out somewhere (just to get a visual cue) , does it show what you expect?

Comment: @Martin get_query_var( 'paged' ) returns an empty string so $paged always takes the value 1

Comment: Try refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281395/wordpress-pagination-get-current-page-number-from-url/14864528 and see if that helps with your issue.